# How to connect Xampp v3.2.1(php) with Ingres

Tags: php, database, xampp, ingres

I want to connect php with the Database located in INGRES. Now, when i try to connect show me it.

[image: This is message show me]

I copied the file `php_ingres` into the folder `php/ext` and added the filename into the file `php.ini`.

The version:

- PHP 5.5.28
- Xampp v3.2.1

Any idea how to resolve it or if there's another way to connect to Ingress database?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in php manual on installing ingres extension? http://php.net/manual/en/ingres.installation.php

Comment: I fix this issue doing this Install Ingres 10.1.0 Community edition: http://esd.ingres.com/product/Community_Projects/Ingres_Database/Windows_32-Bit/Ingres_10.1_Build_121/ingres-10.1.0-121-gpl-win-x86-NoDoc.zip/http

PHP drivers here: http://esd.ingres.com/product/drivers/PHP/Windows_32-Bit/PHP_Driver